# How to write stored procedure for select statment in postgersql

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-9.5

I want to create stored procedure for select statment below is procedure i have created but it giving data ouput blank

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.deactivate_unpaid_accounts()
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    
AS $BODY$
select * from employees where salary=10000
$BODY$;

CALL deactivate_unpaid_accounts();
```

Comment: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  (and didn't support stored procedures to begin with). You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Procedures (which weren't available in 9.5 to begin with) are not intended to return result sets.

If you want to return a result, you should use a function in Postgres.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.deactivate_unpaid_accounts() 
  returns setof employees
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $BODY$ 
  select * 
  from employees 
  where salary=10000;
 $BODY$;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from deactivate_unpaid_accounts();
```